# How can I show the previous view controller in my UINavigationController's stack underneath a new view controller pushed to the stack?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I want to push a view controller to my `UINavigationController`'s stack but still let the previous view controller on the stack peek through. How can I do this? If I was using presentation APIs like `presentViewController:animated:` etc., I would use `modalPresentationStyle`, but I don't think I can here.

Comment: If you show a view controller modally, the previous view controller will be visible underneath. I know this is not what you're looking for, but it might help you find a workaround.